# loss function jumps around with every minibatch

Tags: keras, reinforcement-learning, loss-function, openai-api

I am playing around with keras and  reinforced learning.
I created myself a sort of synthetic input data which looks like this:

[image: input data]

The loss function seems to decrease its value within every episode, but then starts off again from  random value with the beginning of every next minibatch. Looks like the agent forgets everything with every new episode.
The loss function looks like this (2 separate examples, each has 8 episodes, every batch has 100 samples)
[image: Loss function example 1]
[image: Loss function example 2]
What am I missing? What is this a symptom of?

Comment: I think that is a symptom of very unbalanced batches. Since you create random data there is a very real possibility that each batch you need to learn something different